# How to use map published in GeoWebCache With ArcGIS Runtime for Android

Tags: android, geoserver, wms, arcgis-android-api

I want use map published in GeoWebCache with ArcGIS Runtime for Android. I don't now how get the WMS url of a map like ArcGIS sample like this [ArcGIS sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/sample-code/wms-layer-url.htm)

Is there anyone know how to solve it? Thanks very much.